# Square sum vs. Sum square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Is there any condition that make them as equal?

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n (x_i^2+y_i^2) =  \left( \sum_{i=0}^n x_i \right)^2 + \left( \sum_{i=0}^n y_i \right)^2.$$

I think above two equations have difference only in their cross-term such as $x_1x_2$.

Comment: The ([tag:sums-of-squares]) tag is for questions about representations of integers as sums of squares, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/sums-of-squares/info) and [relevant discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12411/what-is-the-tag-sums-of-squares-intended-for).

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n (x_i^2+y_i^2) = \left( \sum_{i=0}^n x_i \right)^2 + \left( \sum_{i=0}^n y_i \right)^2
\iff
\sum_{i,j (i \ne j)} x_ix_j + y_iy_j =0
$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yeah, it is one condition that they become equal! If $x_ix_j$ or $y_iy_j$ is not equal to 0, is there no way to make them equal?

Comment: Since these proof is two sided it **is if and only if**! so this is the only condition!

Comment: @AlbertLEE All he did was subtract your sums from each other, $$\sum_{(i,j), i\ne j}x_ix_j+y_iy_j=(\sum_{i=0}^n x_i)^2+(\sum_{i=0}^n y_i)^2-\sum_{i=0}^n(x_i^2+y_i^2)$$ Which must be equal to zero in order for your sums to be equal.

Comment: @Mahdi Khosravi Thank you for your comment! Now, I have to find the way that $x_ix_j$ and $y_iy_j$ go zero. :)